# Is TIdTCPServer.OnConnect called from the main thread?

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver, delphi-10.3-rio

I don't know if it's ok to access data from the main thread in the `TIdTCPServer.OnConnect` or `OnDisconnect` event. Is this method called from the main thread or other thread? I want to log the IP in a `TMemo`, and enable or disable some buttons.

Comment: Do you know that you can easily test this yourself using the debugger? Set a breakpoint in such a event handler and read the thread ID/name from the debugger.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/VLMxV2tp/screenshot-5.png what does this means ?

Comment: @MarusNebunu it means your `OnConnect` event handler is being called by a `TIdContext` object that is running in a worker thread that is represented by Indy's `TIdThread` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  Its `OnConnect`, `OnDisconnect`, `OnExecute`, and `OnException` events are all fired in the context of a worker thread that is represented by the event's `TIdContext` object.  That thread manages the client TCP connection in the `TIdContext.Connection` property.

The `OnListenException` event is fired in the context of a different worker thread, which listens for client connections and creates the `TIdContext` threads.

So yes, `TIdTCPServer` event handlers must sync with the main thread when accessing UI controls and other shared data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, its getting called in its own thread context.. Better to protect using Synchronize() or Queue()... Example:

```
procedure TMainForm.IdTCPSyncServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  AClientIP: string;
begin
 
  AClientIP := AContext.Binding.PeerIP;
  TThread.Synchronize(nil,
    procedure
    var lItem : TListItem;
    begin
      Inc(FClientCount);
      lblClientConnections.Caption := IntToStr(FClientCount);
      lItem := lstClients.Items.Add;
      lItem.Caption := AClientIP;
      lItem.SubItems.Add(AClientIP);
      lItem.SubItems.Add(DateTimeToStr(Now));
    end
  );
end;
```

Comment: In that kind of example, I would use `TThread.Queue()` instead, to avoid blocking the client thread so it is not dependent on the UI. And I would also store either the `TIdContext` in the `TListItem.Data` property, or the `TListItem` in the `TIdContext.Data` property, so that an `OnDisconnect` event can find the appropriate `TListItem` to remove it from the `TListView`.